# if locked statistics on synonym of table A, gather statistics on the table A throws an error Oracle in 18c?

Tags: oracle18c

I have Oracle 18c db.
Suppose I have a `PUBLIC SYNONYM S_Customer` for table `database1.Customer`

`CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM S_Customer for database1.Customer;`

If locked statistics on `S_Customer`, gather statistics on the `database1.Customer` throws an error Oracle in 18c?

According to https://oraclespin.com/2008/10/09/how-to-lockunlock-statistics-on-a-table/
, if I lock statistics on a table, gather statistics on locked table throws an error.

I'm wondering whether locking the statistic on the synonym of a table will also throws the same error when I gather statistics of the table ( instead of synonym ) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock the statistics of a synonym, only of a table. The name of the procedure is quite clear: `LOCK_TABLE_STATS`, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-77225DE6-28D1-4064-9531-87BB1CFB4405) says "table", and a quick test confirms it:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE SYNONYM s_customer FOR customer;

exec dbms_stats.lock_table_stats(user, 's_customer');

ORA-20000: TABLE "SO"."S_CUSTOMER" does not exist or insufficient privileges
```